# OpenGL GL_Position 3D to 2D Screen Space

Tags: opengl, transformation

I am trying to understand the maths associated with converting a 3D 
point into a 2D screen position. I understand that the process involves moving from object space->worldspace->eye space -> clip Space -> NDC space -> ViewPort space (Final 2D position on screen)

VertexShader:

```
GL_Position =  Projection Matrix * view Matrix * model Matrix * vec(Position,1); => clip space.
```

FragmentShader:

```
(Pseudo code)
  //assuming GL_position is received as a vec4 input variable

  vec2 Gl_position_ndc = (Gl_position.xy/Gl_position.w)/2+ .5; 
  (Gl_position_ndc -> GL_FragColor) after perspective division and converting to Normalized device Coordinate space
```

Do these automatic perspective divides and NDC conversion in the Fragment shader happen automatically to the `GL_Position` received from the Vertex shader as described above in the Fragment shader?

Comment: You do not receive `GL_Position` in the fragment shader. You get `gl_FragCoord` (window-space). See my answer for more details. This is the viewport-defined coordinate space with depth range applied and one special characteristic for its `w` coordinate.

Comment: Thnx Andon for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, division by `w` is automatic after you output the clip-space vertex in the vertex shader.

It happens before rasterization, and therefore before the fragment shader runs. Now, one interesting quirk is that in window-space (`gl_FragCoord`) in a fragment shader, `w` = **1/clip_w**. If you try to do this divide again using `gl_FragCoord`, you actually undo the perspective division and things will get weird.

*There are reasons you might want to divide by **1/clip.w**, but this is not one of them.*